# Getting my JS function to display at the right point

Tags: javascript, function

I'm having a rough time with JS and need some help.  This is my first time using JS and I'm building a memory game for a course project. I have made a modal to pop up when you complete the puzzle.  At the moment the modal pops up at the start, as the puzzle is in tact before the player scrambles it. I need it to appear once the puzzle has been scrambled and then put back together. My confidence level is pretty low at the moment so any advice would be much appreciated. I've dropped my code in below if anyone can help?

```
function swapTiles(cell1, cell2) {
  var temp = document.getElementById(cell1).className;
  document.getElementById(cell1).className = document.getElementById(cell2).className;
  document.getElementById(cell2).className = temp;

}

function shuffle() {
  //Use nested loops to access each cell of the 3x3 grid
  for (var row = 1; row <= 3; row++) { //For each row of the 3x3 grid
    for (var column = 1; column <= 3; column++) { //For each column in this row

      var row2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1); //Pick a random row from 1 to 3
      var column2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1); //Pick a random column from 1 to 3

      swapTiles("cell" + row + column, "cell" + row2 + column2); //Swap the look & feel of both cells
    }
  }
}


function clickTile(row, column) {
  var cell = document.getElementById("cell" + row + column);
  var tile = cell.className;
  if (tile != "tile9-3x3") {
    //Checking if white tile on the right
    if (column < 3) {
      if (document.getElementById("cell" + row + (column + 1)).className == "tile9-3x3") {
        swapTiles("cell" + row + column, "cell" + row + (column + 1));
        return;
      }
    }
    //Checking if white tile on the left
    if (column > 1) {
      if (document.getElementById("cell" + row + (column - 1)).className == "tile9-3x3") {
        swapTiles("cell" + row + column, "cell" + row + (column - 1));
        return;
      }
    }
    //Checking if white tile is above
    if (row > 1) {
      if (document.getElementById("cell" + (row - 1) + column).className == "tile9-3x3") {
        swapTiles("cell" + row + column, "cell" + (row - 1) + column);
        return;
      }
    }
    //Checking if white tile is below
    if (row < 4) {
      if (document.getElementById("cell" + (row + 1) + column).className == "tile9-3x3") {
        swapTiles("cell" + row + column, "cell" + (row + 1) + column);
        return;
      }
    }
  }

}

//Completing the puzzle
function checkWin() {
  //Checks if all tiles are aligned in row 1
  var row1 = document.getElementById("row1");
  for (var i = 0; i < row1.children.length; i++) {
    var n = i + 1;
    if (row1.children[i].className != "tile" + n.toString() + "-3x3") {
      return false;
    }
  }
  //Checks if all tiles are aligned in row 2
  var row2 = document.getElementById("row2");
  for (var i = 0; i < row2.children.length; i++) {
    var n = i + 4;
    if (row2.children[i].className != "tile" + n.toString() + "-3x3") {
      return false;
    }
  }
  //Checks if all tiles are aligned in row 3
  var row3 = document.getElementById("row3");
  for (var i = 0; i < row3.children.length; i++) {
    var n = i + 7;
    if (row3.children[i].className != "tile" + n.toString() + "-3x3") {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

var win = checkWin();
if (win == checkWin()) {
  $('#win-modal').modal('show');
  audio.rickAudio.play();
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your HTML it's hard to say, but I would guess you need to move your `checkWin` call inside the `clickTile` function. You'll want to check after each click if the move has completed the puzzle. Also, you can remove the `var win = checkWin();` line and simply say `if (checkWin()) { ...`

Comment: `<div id="table-3x3" style="display: table;">
            <div id="row1" style="display: table-row;">
                <div id="cell11" class="tile1-3x3" onclick="clickTile(1,1);swipe();"></div>
                <div id="cell12" class="tile2-3x3" onclick="clickTile(1,2);swipe();"></div>
                <div id="cell13" class="tile3-3x3" onclick="clickTile(1,3);swipe();"></div>
            </div>`...... The code is repeated and amended for rows 2 and 3

Comment: Thanks guys, I've managed to sort it now.